# JS doesn't execute when put outside of page where the id button is present

Tags: javascript, php

I've contact us form that loads in modal. When I put the below script within the page where the form id is present, it works fine but when I take out the script and put them in respective js file, DOM fails to execute.. I see in console it shows: **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at index.php".**

```
<button id="myBtn"> Contact Us </button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

/** form fields**/

 </div>
</div>


var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to wait for the window to load, you're trying to bind the event listener before the element exists. put your code in a window ready block.

Comment: load the particular script in the body tag where you have created your form.Take a try.

Comment: be also careful about the order of your scripts if one variable is declared in one file and used in another (which is generally to avoid unless you have a system that assures completion of file dependencies loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not planning on using jQuery you could consider:

```
window.onload = function(){
//enter code here
}
```

window.onload has wider support than document.ready at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // here your code,
   // the document will be loaded

})
```

Comment: @Debflav The question is tagged `jquery` so I guess it's an option.

Comment: Well, he uses a bootstrap modal, so i think he does use jQuery, he just doesn't know it.

Comment: Ok my bad doesn't saw the tag.

Comment: Sorry guys I just uses javascript.. The code works fine within the page. That would mean identifier is outputting null before the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You should put js code in :

```
window.onload = function(){

//code here
}
```